# how to download xls file from website without file name and extension in URL?

Tags: vb.net, xls

I want to download a file from the website:
http://www.trademap.org/Country_SelProduct_TS.aspx?nvpm=1|||||TOTAL|||2|1|1|1|2|1|2|1|1
no filename and extension in the URL. on webpage, excel icon (up-left) has to be on-clicked and then the browser savedfiledialog opens. how to automate this and save the file in pc without browser, from vb.net?
can it be done by webclient.downloadfile?
thanks

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Your analysis/ thought process/ code etc. I also recommend that you complete our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read our [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) center to understand what is on-topic for this site.

Comment: You should google and read a litle bit more on HTML form. Basically, you need a webclient or httpclient to connect to the page. then make it look like you are clicking on the INPUT for excel file by sending the request with the same information as if you are clicking on the link. This is the line you are looking for:  <input type="image" name="ctl00$PageContent$GridViewPanelControl$ImageButton_ExportExcel" id="ctl00_PageContent_GridViewPanelControl_ImageButton_ExportExcel" title="Excel file" src="img/excel.png" alt="Excel file" style="border-width:0px;" />

Comment: thanks a billion for your quick reply, but how should the code be  written? with what class or object? webbrowser, webclient or etc?

Comment: Done! software is working great! the code i used is webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("ElementID").invokemember("click")