# how to download a file with its cookie and URL?

Tags: vb.net, file, cookies, download, automation

I have a big problem downloading .xlsx files from a site automatically.
I have tried the following code and cookie is ready:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(("http://www.trademap.org/Country_SelProduct_TS.aspx?nvpm=1|||||0101|||4|1|1|1|2|1|2|1|1")), HttpWebRequest)
request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
For Each cook As Cookie In response.Cookies
msgbox(cook.value)
Next
```

I have the cookie but don't know how to download the file using the cookie and the URL without being asked. Can it be done by webclient.downloadfile or something like that?

Comment: you aren't the first one to ask about downloading files from that website. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457912/how-to-download-xls-file-from-website-without-file-name-and-extension-in-url?rq=1

Comment: @Chillzy That was the OP too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second request has to use the same CookieContainer object to share its information.

```
Dim cookieContainer as New CookierContainer()

Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(("http://www.trademap.org/Country_SelProduct_TS.aspx?nvpm=1|||||0101|||4|1|1|1|2|1|2|1|1")), HttpWebRequest)
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer 
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

Dim request2 as HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("second url"), HttpWebRequest);
request2.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
Dim response2 As HttpWebResponse = CType(request2.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "second URL" and sending the second request? could you please help me with the full code that I can completely download the .xlsx file. thanks. by the way, I am not a pro computer programmer.

Comment: You are passing Cooke's between requests?...this is how you do that